# "Zu in" als Doppelpräposition?

Tags: meaning, preposition

Was ist der Zweck oder die Bedeutung von "zu" im folgenden Satz?

> Vor ihm lag ein langer, schmaler Raum, der sich nach hinten zu im
> Dämmerlicht verlor.

Spielt dieses "zu" seine Rolle als Präposition, um vielleicht auszudrücken, dass sich dieser Raum zum (also Richtung von) Dämmerlicht erstreckt, und dann schließlich im Dämmerlicht verschwindet? Haben wir also eine Doppelpräposition?

Oder ist "nach hinten zu" eins von diesen Vor-Nach-Dings, wie z. B. "von dort aus".

Auf jeden fall lerne ich seit ein paar Jahren Deutsch und habe jetzt gerade zum ersten Mal ein solches "zu in" gesehen.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Das Vor-Nach-Dings heisst *Zirkumposition*, ist sehr selten und verwendet meistens Formen, die auch als normale Präposition vorkommen, z.B. *von ... an* oder *von ... her* (nur um extra Verwirrung zu stiften).  Der Ausdruck "nach hinten zu" bedeutet hier nichts anderes als "in Richtung der Rückwand".

Comment: Danke... bedeutet dann "nach hinten zu" etwas anderes als einfach "nach hinten" (in diesem Fall oder im Allgemeinen)?

Comment: "Nach hinten" wird tendenziell benutzt, wenn etwas sich tatsächlich bewegt: "Ich gehe nach hinten ins Lager." "Nach hinten zu" wird fast nur benutzt, wenn ein Weg/Raum/Gebäude im übertragenen Sinn in eine bestimmte Richtung "verläuft", wobei aber alle Teile unbeweglich bleiben.